# Can't reach ngrok routes

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, ngrok

I have this k8s setup on AWS for learning purposes and used ngrok to access the `'/'` path, but on adding other paths like `'/alertmanager'`, `'/wordpress'` I can reach these paths. I am wondering if my ngrok ingress manifest is valid. Here it is:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: prometheus-operated
  namespace: default
spec:
  ingressClassName: ngrok
  rules:
  - host: pheasant-singular-obviously.ngrok-free.app
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: alertmanager-operated
            port:
              number: 9093
      - path: /wordpress
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: wordpress
            port:
              number: 8000
      - path: /prometheus
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: prometheus-operated
            port:
              number: 9090
```

and these are my services on my k8s:

```
NAME                    TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
alertmanager-operated   ClusterIP   None             <none>        9093/TCP,9094/TCP,9094/UDP   5d7h
kubernetes              ClusterIP   10.xxx.xxx.1        <none>        443/TCP                      6d14h
prometheus-operated     ClusterIP   None             <none>        9090/TCP                     5d9h
prometheus-operator     ClusterIP   None             <none>        8080/TCP                     5d9h
wordpress               NodePort    10.xx5.xxx.106   <none>        8000:32217/TCP               4h38m
wordpress-mysql         ClusterIP   None             <none>        3306/TCP                     4h38m
```

Running the `kubectl describe pod ...` command produces this:

```
....
Events:
  Type     Reason          Age                From     Message
  ----     ------          ----               ----     -------
  Normal   SandboxChanged  36m (x3 over 36m)  kubelet  Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
  Warning  Unhealthy       35m (x3 over 35m)  kubelet  Readiness probe failed: Get "http://192.168.83.237:8081/readyz": dial tcp 192.168.83.237:8081: connect: connection refused
  Warning  Unhealthy       35m                kubelet  Liveness probe failed: Get "http://192.168.83.237:8081/healthz": dial tcp 192.168.83.237:8081: connect: connection refused
  Warning  BackOff         35m                kubelet  Back-off restarting failed container ngrok-ingress-controller in pod ngrok-ingress-controller-kubernetes-ingress-controller-mannzc7m_ngrok-ingress-controller(9500428d-b3b2-43de-9259-6820cfa795dc)
  Normal   Pulled          35m (x2 over 36m)  kubelet  Container image "docker.io/ngrok/kubernetes-ingress-controller:0.8.0" already present on machine
  Normal   Created         35m (x2 over 36m)  kubelet  Created container ngrok-ingress-controller
  Normal   Started         35m (x2 over 36m)  kubelet  Started container ngrok-ingress-controller
  Warning  Unhealthy       34m                kubelet  Liveness probe failed: Get "http://192.168.83.237:8081/healthz": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
  Warning  Unhealthy       34m (x3 over 35m)  kubelet  Readiness probe failed: Get "http://192.168.83.237:8081/readyz": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

---

```
kubectl get tunnel
NAME                         FORWARDSTO                                             AGE
alertmanager-operated-9093   alertmanager-operated.default.svc.cluster.local:9093   96s
wordpress-8000               wordpress.default.svc.cluster.local:8000               32h
```

---

```
kubectl get domain
NAME                                          ID                               REGION   DOMAIN                                       CNAME TARGET   AGE
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx2-ngrok-free-app    rd_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx            xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx2-ngrok-free-app                  7d15h
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx2-ngrok-free-app                                                                                                         7d14h
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx2-ngrok-free-app                                                                                                              7d15h
```

---

```
kubectl get tunnel
NAME                         FORWARDSTO                                             AGE
alertmanager-operated-9093   alertmanager-operated.default.svc.cluster.local:9093   4m15s
wordpress-8000               wordpress.default.svc.cluster.local:8000               32h
```

The `kubectl logs ...`:

```
{"level":"error","ts":"2023-08-01T12:25:24Z","msg":"Reconciler error","controller":"domain","controllerGroup":"ingress.k8s.ngrok.com","controllerKind":"Domain","Domain":{"name":"pheasant-singular-obviously2-ngrok-free-app","namespace":"default"},"namespace":"default","name":"pheasant-singular-obviously2-ngrok-free-app","reconcileID":"6838c603-ad86-47a7-9675-1a4e19eaefff","error":"HTTP 400: Only Personal, Pro or Enterprise accounts can reserve domains.\nYour account can't reserve domains. \n\nUpgrade to a paid plan at: https://dashboard.ngrok.com/billing/subscription [ERR_NGROK_401]\n\nOperation ID: op_2TNo6ZP4Tfhgiz6jOSNhWxkg9Ik","stacktrace":"sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/controller.(*Controller).reconcileHandler\n\tsigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.14.1/pkg/internal/controller/controller.go:329\nsigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/controller.(*Controller).processNextWorkItem\n\tsigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.14.1/pkg/internal/controller/controller.go:274\nsigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/controller.(*Controller).Start.func2.2\n\tsigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.14.1/pkg/internal/controller/controller.go:235"}
```